# Localstack error in Step function with DefinitionS3Location

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, localstack

I am trying to deploy a lambda and a step function in `localstack`. I keep my step-function-definition in `s3`.

The [cloudformation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-stepfunctions-statemachine.html) says we can use `DefinitionS3Location` instead of using `Definition` or `DefinitionString`.

This is what I am doing.

`template.yml`:

```
# Lambda function
  EndToEndTestLambdaFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 1024
      PackageType: Zip
      CodeUri: s3://step-lambda-zip-artifacts/index.zip
      Role: !GetAtt IAMRole.Arn

  # Step function
  EndToEndTestStepFunction:
    Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
    Properties:
      DefinitionS3Location:
        Bucket: step-lambda-zip-artifacts
        Key: endToEndTestRunner.json
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        EndToEndTestLambdaFunctionArn: !GetAtt EndToEndTestLambdaFunction.Arn
      RoleArn: !GetAtt IAMRole.Arn
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:0.12.15
    container_name: localstack_fundle
    #    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=iam, lambda, dynamodb, apigateway, s3, sns, cloudwatch, ssm, stepfunctions, sqs, cloudformation
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker-reuse
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
      - STEPFUNCTIONS_LAMBDA_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4566
    volumes:
      - my-datavolume:/tmp/localstack
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
volumes:
  my-datavolume:
```

As per the `cloudformation` doc, the `definition` is optional and I am using the s3 location for the definition. But each time I try to deploy I get the error:

> DEBUG:localstack.utils.cloudformation.template_deployer: Error applying changes for CloudFormation stack "development-localstack-Test": Parameter validation failed:
> | Missing required parameter in input: "definition"

It's weird because it does not go with the doc!

At first I had the impression that the problem is from the `cloudformation` but it is not. Found a [`localstack` issue](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/4099) about this but no solution over there.

Is this actually a `localstack` issue and is there a way to make this work?

Comment: This seems to be a localstack issue and not an AWS issue. Since you're deploying on localstack and not AWS, you also cannot depend on the AWS documentation, since localstack will have a different implementation and might not be fully compliant, which I guess is the case here.

Comment: Yeah, I found out that. But the question is what is the solution to work this out with localstack? I cannot find anything how to make it work with localstack!!!

Comment: As you've linked an open issue on the localstack GitHub repository yourself, that is about this problem, it seems that this cannot be done. No amount of exclamation points is going to change that.